# applications for converting gif to image sequence, and vice versa

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, graphics

I'm looking for a simple application that i can use to turn image sequences into gifs, and split gifs into image sequences for mac OS. i know there are online resources but i need something i can use when I'm not hooked up to the internet. I also use the application processing for various things, so if anyone knows where i can find a simple java scrip for this, that would also help. It would be an added bonus if it can also do the same back forth conversion for video too but not necessary since i already have tools for this.

Comment: Please consider explaining what os you seek this since this could be iOS or macOS. Using the edit function above is best to change the text and tags

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Gifrocket.app` or `Drop to Gif.app`, both work offline. If you want to edit the sequence/pictures that make up the gif, you can just open your Gif in Preview.app

Comment: can either of these convert GIF back to an image sequence?

Comment: You don't need an especial software to get the images back. Just use Preview.app, it will give you any specific or range of images you want.

Comment: i know i can drag and drop each frame one at a time into finder to get .tiff images, but if i grab multiple it either only puts out one image or the whole gif sequence. is there a way to export all frames as a separate jpg or png images at once?